# FancyBox, navigation arrows outside the IFrames and SWFs

Tags: jquery, fancybox

For anyone who wants to move navigation arrows outside the picture and make them permanently visible I have changed the default CSS style sheet (jquery.fancybox.css) all the changes I made are at the end of the file. You can download the file from the following link

http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?gcs51e1z2np14nj

It works flawlessly for pictures but I seem not to be able to make it work for iframes and swfs. In case of iframes it just pushes the arrows outside the content area but it is still inside the fancybox frame.

If anyone knows the solution please share it.